# How do I take a screenshot on a Windows Phone device?

Tags: functionality

On iOS devices you can take a screenshot by pressing the home & sleep buttons at the same time. Is there a similar way to take a screenshot with Windows Phone?

Comment: You can cast a vote [here](http://windowsphone.uservoice.com/forums/101801-feature-suggestions/suggestions/2281126-screenshot-support). That's the official place to make requests.

Comment: Yes, this functionality will appear in WP8.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

For devices still running Windows Phone 8, hold the power button and then press the Windows key. The screenshot will then be stored in a "Screenshots" album in the photos.

For those updated to Windows Phone 8.1, press and hold <kbd>power</kbd>+<kbd>volume up</kbd> simultaneously.

There is a video [guide from Microsoft on YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pxi5uYX-5-E)

Comment: Ref: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pxi5uYX-5-E

Answer (score 25):

There are a few ways to take screenshots:

1. If you're just a developer and just want to take screenshots for marketing your app, you can use the [emulator's screenshot tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg442300%28v=VS.92%29.aspx).
2. If you have a developer-unlocked phone ([$99 a year from Microsoft](http://create.msdn.com/), or via unofficial tools) you can use [third-party apps like the one described here](http://www.winsupersite.com/article/windowsphone75/windows-phone-75-screenshots-141063).

Comment: Nothing for normal users?

Comment: Unfortunately, no.

Comment: Developer accounts are now $19 a year, I think.

Comment: @peSHIr Really? I thought that was free, last I tried.

Comment: It is now, it wasn't in October of 2013 or April of 2012..

Answer (score 14):

In Windows Phone 8 you are able to save a screenshot by holding both the power button (often on the side of the phone, between the volume buttons and the camera button) and the home button (the middle button under the screen, with the Windows logo on it) for some time. Such screenshots are saved in the Screenshot album of the Picture Hub.

And just to be complete: in Windows Phone 8.1 Preview this combination was changed to holding both the volume up and the power button. If you use the older Windows Phone 8.0 key combination, you get shown a message box that tells you of this change.

For normal users (no developers) in Windows Phone 7.5 and earlier there is *no* way to make a screenshot of your phone except using another camera(phone) to do it. I think this is still the case in the Windows Phone 7.8 update that brings the smaller home screen tiles from Windows Phone 8.

Comment: For wp8 isn't POWER BUTTON and Home key?

Answer (score 3):

### Windows Phone 8

Press and hold Start button and Power icon at the same time to take a picture of your screen.

### Windows Phone 8.1

Press the Power icon and Volume Up buttons at the same time to take a picture of your screen.

### Windows Phone 7, 7.5

It do not provide a way to take screenshots without unlocking the phone with developer tools.

*The screenshot will then be stored into a "Screenshots" album in the photos.*