# Is it possible to save a screen capture?

Tags: settings

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I take a screenshot on a Windows Phone device?](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/23/how-do-i-take-a-screenshot-on-a-windows-phone-device)

I know that applications, can use code to capture screens inside themselves, offering a "Save Screen" like option. The 4th and Mayor application has this. But is there a way for me, the phone user, to randomly do a screen capture of any screen on the phone?

IPhone has Power+Home button == Save screen. Anything like this on WinPhone 7?

Answer (score 4):

There is no built in screen shot capability. However, if you have a developer unlocked device, you can use a third party app.

This tool http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1315847 will let you take a screenshot and save it as an image.