# How do I print out sms message?

Tags: sms, printer

I may need to use some SMS message as part of a legal dispute, therefore how can I print them out?

Answer (score 3):

Currently the easiest way would be to [make a screenshot](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/23/how-do-i-take-a-screenshot-on-a-windows-phone-device) of the conversation and  just print it from your computer.

You'll find your screenshots in the pictures folder when you connect your phone to your PC through USB - or you can email them to yourself.

Windows 10 Mobile will natively support printing, but that might not be soon enough for you.